# I am trying to create Caesar Ciphers functions in Python, but they seem to work only with lower case letter, how to work with upper case?

Tags: python, math, caesar-cipher, letter

I am trying to create Caesar Ciphers functions in Python, but they seem to work only with lower case letter, how to work with upper case?

```
a = dict(zip("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",range(26)))
b = dict(zip(range(26),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))

key = int(input('Enter the key:'))
plaintext = (input('Enter your message:'))


ciphertext = ""
for c in plaintext:
    if c.isalpha():
        ciphertext += b[ (a[c] + key)%26 ]
    else: ciphertext += c


plaintext2 = ""
for c in ciphertext:
   if c.isalpha(): 
        plaintext2 += b[ (a[c] - key)%26 ]
    else: plaintext2 += c


print(plaintext,",",ciphertext,",",plaintext2)
```

Comment: What do you want to happen for upper case letters? Should it be two domains, so that upper case is replaced by upper case and lower case by lower case? Or should upper case just be converted to lower case? Your question is not sufficiently specified.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add the uppercase letters to the dictionary. Otherwise, the program doesn't know what number to map them to.
I would recommend setting variable 
`letters = "abcd..."`
and then adding
`letters = letters + letters.upper()`

at the beginning of the program.

Also, change all 26s to 52s.
Finally, replace "abcd..." with `letters`.